# Multidimensional String arrays are not supported - Vyper

Tags: arrays, python, string, vyper

Whenever I try to make a list of strings (2D array), I get this error `Multidimensional String arrays are not supported`. This is the code I tried: `names: String[30][100]`. Does anyone know how to help? (version 0.3.1)

Comment: Use solidity or manage the array by yourself `names: String[3000]`.

Comment: I figured out how to use a hashmap.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think 2D String arrays are possible now in Vyper 0.3.7.  Example:

```
   DynArray[String[3], 10]
```

Comment: This seems only a little better than my current solution, but I already deployed my site and contract. You can achieve the same thing with the above solution.

Comment: @thegamebegins25 Glad you found a solution that works in your contract!  I'm just learning Vyper.  I didn't deploy a real contract yet.

Comment: Differences that may be important to others:  HashMap is a storage variable only.  It can't be a local variable.  On the other hand, DynArrays can be local or storage variables in a function.  DynArrays can be passed to and returned by functions. I am not sure of the storage cost differences between HashMap and DynArray.

Answer (score 2):

I figured it out, I can use a hashmap.

```
names: HashMap[uint256, String[30]]
```